# Advance Filter with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have three worksheets

1. `ConditionSheet` : Having conditions value in cell `E5` & `E7`
2. `SourceSheet` : Complete Data
3. `TargetSheet` : When I run macro `New worksheet` create with this name based on `conditionSheet` Value.

From `SourceSheet` I want to create new worksheet with specific data.

In `ConditionSheet` Cell `E5` having 1st criteria and `E7` having second Criteria

Based on this I want to create New worksheet name 'TargetSheet'

In this only those data copy from `SourceSheet` whose `Column F` value is match with `E5` Cell value in `ConditionalSheet` & `Column H` of `SourceSheet` value match with `E7` value of `ConditionalSheet`

The Second criteria is optional so I used `IIF` function to pass condition.

Following command copied all the data from `sourcesheet` whether it is one or two condition.

```
Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("A1:AB" & Worksheets("TargetSheet").Rows.Count).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=IIf(Sheets("ConditionSheet").Range("E7") = "", Sheets("ConditionSheet").Range("E5:E5"), Sheets("ConditionSheet").Range("E5:E7")), _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("TargetSheet").Range("A1"), _
Unique:=True
```

I want to copy only data based on criteria.

Please guide me.

(Thanks for viewer and replied users)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, or screenshots? I *think* I understand what you mean, but I'm not certain. I believe you want to only copy rows where SourceSheet!F is the same as ConditionSheet!E5, or SourceSheet!H is the same as ConditionSheet!E7?

Comment: See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.